# JNDI lookup error for name: java:comp/env/jdbc/DynaPropDB

Tags: datasource, jndi, websphere-liberty, open-liberty, pcfdev

Am getting below error while starting the liberty server:
[ERROR   ]

```
com.it.properties.PropertyResourceException for user [UnKnown] self logged on Jan 23, 2019 12:43:12 PM.
Exception instance reference code [13EE91EC-BCA0-49C1-7ABC-5F537ABC5F53].
```

---

1. I have DynaPropAdminWeb Access for the application
2. Correctly placed lookup-name and binding-name in web.xml file and ibm-web-bnd.xml file

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you provide the relevant web.xml, ibm-web-bnd.xml, and server.xml config snippets for the resource reference and data source.  Absent that, taking your word that the deployment descriptor and binding file are correct, then the problem will be in the server config, either in incorrectly specifying the dataSource/jdbcDriver/library or with feature enablement.  A common mistake in Liberty is forgetting to enable the jndi-1.0 feature (which is needed for JNDI lookups) alongside the jdbc-4.x feature.  In case that is the problem, here is an example,

```
<server>
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jdbc-4.2</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
  </featureManager>

  <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/DynaPropDB">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="jdbcLib"/>
    <properties serverName="localhost" portNumber="1234" databaseName="exampleDB"/>
  </dataSource>

  <library id="jdbcLib">
    <file name="C:/drivers/jdbc/myJdbcDriver.jar"/>
  </library>
</server>
```

Also, here is a [link to a knowledge center page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html) with configuration examples for various commonly-used databases.

Comment: My featureMangers contain:
        <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
  <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
  <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
  <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
  <feature>ldapRegistry-3.0</feature>
  <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
  <feature>jsf-2.0</feature>
  <feature>cdi-1.0</feature>
  <feature>javaMail-1.5</feature>
  <feature>wsSecurity-1.1</feature>
  <feature>beanValidation-1.0</feature>
  <feature>concurrent-1.0</feature>
     <feature>ejbLite-3.1</feature>

Comment: That's good - you are already including jndi-1.0.  Would you be able to share the relevant snippets from your web.xml and ibm-web-bnd.xml and the dataSource and library elements from your server.xml ?